# Can not update to ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

When I am in the update manager, it says that I have to upgrade 
(*You will not get any further security fixes or critical updates. Please upgrade to a later version of Ubuntu Linux.*) 
but when I try, there jumps out a window saying 
*"Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server."* 
**What shall I do?**